How to unset environment variables using a bash script
I tried to use a bash script to add or remove proxies in bulk, but the script runs with confusing results.
I can add proxies in bulk using the following code. This code is saved by me in use_proxy.sh：
#!/bin/bash
PROXY="http://127.0.0.1:10889"
set_proxy() {
    export http_proxy="$PROXY"
    export https_proxy="$PROXY"
    export HTTP_PROXY="$PROXY"
    export HTTPS_PROXY="$PROXY"
    echo "代理已设置为 $PROXY"
}
set_proxy

When I run this script (bash use_proxy.sh) with the bash command, everything works fine, and running the env command does add the proxy address
But I am not able to remove proxies in bulk using the following code, which is saved in unset_proxy.sh:
#!/bin/bash
unset_proxy() {
    unset http_proxy 
    unset https_proxy 
    unset HTTP_PROXY 
    unset HTTPS_PROXY
    echo "代理已取消"
}
unset_proxy

When I use this script (i.e. run the bash unset_proxy.sh), this script does not work. When I run the env command, I still see the proxy address previously set by use_proxy.sh
Why?

I found that if the script is run using source (aka source unset_proxy.sh) it executes successfully.
So now I have a new question: why does bash unset_proxy.sh fail to unset the environment variable correctly, while source unset_proxy.sh will successfully unset the environment variable?

Please [edit] the question and show us the actual scripts (if you have a shebang line, please show it since telling us it is "ignored" is confusing). Also explain how you run these scripts. Are they really separate scripts which you execute or do you make the functions available to your current shell? Do you run /path/to/script.sh or . /path/to/script.sh?

OK,my bad.I will fix it

The first one doesn't work either, how are you checking it? Why do you think it works? I suspect you already had the HTTP_PROXY variables set before running the script because what you show wouldn't set them in the current shell.

The why is as I explain in my answer: this is how sourcing works. Sourcing runs things in your current shell, while executing a script runs in a new subshell. See What is the difference between sourcing ('.' or 'source') and executing a file in bash?

When you run a shell script, that is run in a separate shell process. This means you cannot run a script to set or unset variables in your current shell and exporting the variable makes no difference. Take a trivial example:
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash
export foo="bar"
echo "Foo in the script is '$foo'"

$ $ ./foo.sh 
Foo in the script is 'bar'

$ echo "Foo outside the script is: '$foo'"
Foo outside the script is: ''

As you can see, running the script didn't set the variable. However, sourcing the script using . (or, if your shell is bash, using source which is the same thing), which will run the commands in the current shell, does allow you to set and unset variables:
$ . ./foo.sh 
Foo in the script is 'bar'
$ echo "Foo outside the script is: '$foo'"
Foo outside the script is: 'bar'

So, using . instead of running the scripts will probably be what you need. Even simpler, add the two functions to your ~/.bashrc and then you can just run them in any shell and have them work natively. No need for separate scripts, just copy paste the code directly into your ~/.bashrc.
See What is the difference between sourcing ('.' or 'source') and executing a file in bash?

The first one, if it doesn't run, is probably because this code is abbreviated from a large section of code (the source code is generated by chatgpt and is a bit long), I'm very sorry.
Then, thank you very much for your help. I successfully added the proxy using bash use_proxy.sh, which led me to believe that bash was using the current shell directly. Thanks for the correction!

@djakkk I really, really doubt you actually successfully added the variables using that script since, as I explain in this answer, that is impossible. I am guessing you checked that the variables were set from inside the script. That would work, the variables were indeed set in the environment of the script, but only there. As soon as the script exited, the variables were gone since they only ever existed in the environment of the script.

t: or OP at some point, possibly hours or days earlier, (1) did source/. set.sh or (2) did the assignments directly, and (much) later ran set.sh as a script and subsequently observed the envvars were (still!) set
